# Proof for the nature of an eigenvector given a small eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**The problem:**

In the below question we are allowed to use theorems a, b, and c in order to arrive at the proof for theorem d.
[image]

I use contradiction to assume that the eigenvector has all rational entries, but after that I get stuck. I'm not sure which contradiction I'm meant to reach to show the assumption is false. I've tried multiplying both side by $N$ and then by $\lambda$, but I can't get anywhere.

Any suggestions or hints as to what course I should take to solve this?

Comment: The theorem is clearly not meant to be tackled all at once. It gives you three stepping stones that lead you to the proof of the full theorem (i.e. part (d)). Did you try following these steps? If so, how far did you get? The assumption that the eigenvector has all rational entries seems pointless for answering part (a) for example.

Comment: Apply part (c) to $\vec{w}$ from part (b). Then apply it to $A\vec{w}$. Then to $A^2\vec{w}$. Show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}||A^n\vec{w}||=0.$$ Do you see why that is a contradiction with part (a)?

Answer (score 2):

Assume, to the contrary, that there is a $\lambda$-eigenvector $v$ of $A$ with rational entries.

By (b), without loss of generality, we may assume that $v$ has integer entries.

Then by (a), $Av=\lambda v$ has integer entries as well.

Since $v$ itself has integer entries, $\lambda$ can only be a rational number, say $p/q$.

However, consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is a monic polynomial over integers. By rational zeros theorem, we must have $q=1$ whence $\lambda$ is an integer. This is clearly impossible as $0<|\lambda|<1$.

(This somewhat gets round of part (c). If anyone knows how to use (c) to get a contradiction, please let me know.)

Comment: Thanks for this!

Comment: There are only finitely many *integer* vectors shorter than any given vector. Alternatively: what is the shortest eigenvector with integer entries?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the hint!

Comment: The idea of using the rational zeros theorem gives a different (valid) approach to the big theorem. I guess that whoever designed this exercise wanted to use another idea. Good for learners to see different ways of settling the matter. As a teacher I confess that the first few times it was a chastening experience when students side stepped my sequence of hints altogether, and came up with a simpler argument. Nowadays I take it in stride :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector with rational entries.

By (b), there is another $\lambda$-eigenvector $w$ with integer entries.

Without loss of generality we can assume the entries of $w$ have GCD equal to $1$ (otherwise we can divide $w$ by the GCD to arrive at this case).

By (a), $Aw = \lambda w$ also has integer entries. Since $\lambda = \frac{\lambda w_i}{w_i}$ for each $i$, we know $\lambda$ is rational; let $\lambda = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Therefore, $q$ is a [nontrivial] common divisor of the entries of $w$, which contradicts our above assumption that the entries of $w$ had has GCD $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response!